# I am unable to click on a link with class selectable using watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir

I been trying to click on a link with **class "selectable"** without success.

The html code is as display below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
    <label class="selectable col-xs-offset-2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkNoEmail" data-bind="checked: noEmail, attr: { 'disabled': baseController.readonly() }">
    </label>
    <a class="selectable" data-toggle="popover" data-bind="click: baseController.noEmailClicked, popover: { title: '', customClass: 'popover-lrg popover-alert', contentHtmlId: 'noEmailAlert', onlyIf: function () { return noEmail() } }" data-original-title="" title="">no email</a>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" data-bind="value: email, attr: { 'disabled': noEmail() || baseController.readonly() }"><span class="validationMessage" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

I have try using the parent div and also using

```
browser.selectable(:text, /no email/).click
```

and

```
browser.selectable(:text, /no email/).fire_event("onclick") but not success.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without success"? Is there an exception or is it just not doing anything?

Comment: it is not doing anything, the expected behaviour is for a tooltip to appear

Comment: `selectable` is not an element type. Are you sure an exception does not occur for the examples you gave?

Comment: I have also try `browser.link(:text, /no email/).click` and got no Action, I will follow up with the person that developed this and see what is triggering the display of the tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this.

```
@browser.div(:class => "forum-group").label(:class => "selectable").check
```

However, I am not sure you can do a ".check" on a label element. You could also try

```
@browser.div(:class => "forum-group").checkbox(:id => "chkNoEmail").check
```

Or, since I dont think it is an actual check box, you could try ".click" instead of ".check" on either one of them, I still do not think you can do either action on a label element though.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I also try with the native java script events and this also worked. `@browser.div(:text, 'no email').fire_event :click`